# BusyBox: dropping to build-in shell: initramfs problem with encrypted hard drive

Tags: boot, encryption, initramfs, busybox

I tried to do an upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 on my laptop. When I came back a bit later, the machine had crashed. I restarted it and it had got in a pickle halfway through the upgrade process. I did all the recommended stuff like `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. At some point when executing all of these remedial commands the machine lost the ability to reboot. I have an encrypted hard drive and instead of prompting me for the password, I was getting an `evms_activate is not available` error message. I tried to follow the commands [here](http://blog.leenix.co.uk/2012/07/evmsactivate-is-not-available-on-boot.html) but I'm not sure I did them right as I have a separate boot partition. Now when I boot it gives up waiting for my root device and drops into an `initramfs` shell with the message

```
ALERT! /dev/mapper/W530-root does not exist.
```

When I check `/proc/cmdline' as recommended I see that it looks like

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic root=/dev/mapper/W530-root ro quiet splash
```

and when I look do `ls /dev/mapper` I just see the `control` file.

I really don't know what I've misconfigured and any help would be appreciated as I just seem to be getting my machine in a worse and worse state. I've looked at some of the other questions with similar symptoms on askubuntu and they don't seem to help.